# How can i check if the user is authenticated or not in base.html in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, authentication

If the user anonymous or not, how can i check that in base.html?

Which is correct?

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

Or

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

How can i pass the variable `request.user` in base.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Request context:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

# in a view
return render_to_response('base.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Make sure you take a look at these context processors: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth

And then you should be able to access `user` in your templates

You can use the django shortcut `render` to always render a template that is automatically passed a RequestContent:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#module-django.shortcuts

Comment: All templates extend `base.html` and you didn't pass any context there. So do i have to pass in every view method in this way? `return render_to_response('base.html',{'user': request.user, context_instance = RequestContext(request))` that's not good idea to pass `request.user` in every view method.

Comment: You do not need to explicitly pass the user object in. It will be made available by passing a RequestContext. You would do this in views that need to pass the Request into the template.

Comment: The `base.html` is common for whole project, in `base.html` it needs to check whether it's a logged in user or not, based on that it will print login or logout anchor link.

Comment: See my latest update to use the `render` shortcut. yes your response needs to always include a RequestContext, and this will do it by default.